# Why isn't NSS using mDNS?

Tags: 14.04, networking, dns, avahi

I have a machine that is unable to resolve hostnames over mDNS:

```
### mDNS is working
$ avahi-resolve -n foo.local
foo.local   1.2.3.4

### NSS is configured to use mDNS
$ grep ^hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf 
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns

### But something's not working in practice...
$ getent hosts foo.local   # returns empty
```

For the avoidance of doubt, `getent hosts` returns successful/correct results both for names that are defined in `/etc/hosts` and for names that are resolved via unicast DNS.

Rebooting resolves the problem, but I'd like to know what's going wrong/how it can be fixed without a reboot.

Presumably `libnss-mdns` needs a kick of some sort, though I get the impression from [nsswitch.conf: is there a daemon I need to restart?](https://serverfault.com/q/76853) that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I can't think of anything to suggest except running an strace on `getent hosts foo.local` when it fails; on my 14.04 box it appears to connect to the avahi-daemon via /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket so you could stat that I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this on a 16.04 box. Shame I wasted hours not realising that the simple solution is to bounce the box.

From what I've seen with bsd I suspect the service that needs to be restarted is dbus. Reference for that is https://revprez.github.io/posts/2016-06-26-avahi-conquered.html

Comment: Restarting dbus on a running desktop environment will not be fun, btw.